# Сделать указатель на одномерный массив в c++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Нужно сделать два указателя на массив(одномерный и двумерный), проблема в том что я не понимаю как сделать на одномерный, по заданию нужно спросить у юзера на какой указатель сослаться и вывести массив. Вот что сейчас творится у меня в коде, хелпаните

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//функция выводит массив на экран

void printArr(int **arr, const int row, const int column)
{
    cout << "\n\nMassiv:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j];

        cout << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    const int row = 4, column = 4; //размеры массива
    int **arr = new int*[row];        //двумерный массив


    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vvodim " << i + 1 << " stroku\n";
        arr[i] = new int[column];

        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            cout << "Vvedite celoe chislo: ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    printArr(arr, row, column);


    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
            if (arr[i][j] != arr[j][i])
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << (flag ? "Symmetric" : "asymmetrical") << endl;

    cout << endl;

    if (flag == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
            {
                if (i > j) arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; ++i)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < row; ++j)
            {
                 swap(arr[i][j], arr[j][i]);
            }



    }

    printArr(arr, row, column);


    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;



    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Если уж разобрались с двумерным даже. Ведь двумерный массив это указатель на указатель. Вам всего лишь надо убрать одно звено

Одномерный указатель, если проблема в этом, задается таким образом, например:

`int m[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *tmp = m;`

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev , я задал двумерный массив через двойной указатель а теперь мне нужно через одинарный указатель и с этим проблема,  а потом еще и вывести обаварианта

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос действительно в том, как создать указатель на двумерный массив, а не указатель на указатель, то вот вариант его объявления:

```
int (*arr_p)[6];
```

Указатель на двумерный массив с 6-ю столбцами.

Если же вопрос в указателе на одинарный массив, то:

```
int *arr_p = mas; // где mas - одномерный массив
```

Но не забывайте, что если хотите изначально получить указатель не на первый элемент массива, а один из следующих, то надо использовать:

```
*(arr_p + n) = mas; // где n - сдвиг
```

И учитывать еще одну вещь, что без скобок `*arr_p + n` увеличит первый элемент массива на n

Comment: Я этих способов уже много видел, я не знаю как это применить к своему коду